# User Data from a table, in relation to another table?

Tags: php, mysql, function, join

I'd like to create a function that takes the data of a table, where the username from the first table `users` is the same as the owner from the second table `pets`. I want to be able to recall any item from the field with either `$pet_data['fieldname']` or `pet_data['fieldname']` A general answer would be fine, as I'm okay at editing code xD Here's my user_data function, which I tried to apply what I wanted to, which didn't work:

```
function user_data($user_id) {
  $data = array();
  $user_id = (int)$user_id;
  $func_num_args = func_num_args();
   $func_get_args = func_get_args();
  if ($func_num_args > 1) {
    unset($func_get_args[0]);
    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"));
    return $data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace you query with this one:

```
SELECT $fields FROM `users`, `pets`
WHERE `user_id` = $user_id
AND `owner` = $user_id
```

`$fields` may contain column names from either `users` or `pets`. If there are ambiguities on column names, they must be resolved by fully qualifying them (eg. `users.user_id`).

Here's a possible update to your code:

```
$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
$data = mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users`, `pets` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id AND `owner` = $user_id");
if ($data === false) {
    die("error on mysql_query: ". mysql_error());
}
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);
```

Comment: When I try this, I get this error: `Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Nebupets\core\functions\register.php on line 82` (line 82 has the query) and I am using this to get the feilds btw: `$user_data = user_data($session_user_id, 'user_id', 'username', 'first_name', 'email', 'avatar', 'rank', 'petnumber', 'pet_id', 'petname', 'species', 'gender', 'colour', 'level', 'defense', 'agility', 'offense', 'equipment_1', 'equipment_2', 'equipment_3', 'equipment_4', 'equipment_5');` which are most of the fields

Comment: please let me know what the problem is exactly.